# New version of Ionic View Pro with Git not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I followed all the steps to convert my legacy Ionic View app into this pro view,
I linked with new Ionic Pro dashboard app Id , Created SSH Keys ,
All command working fine except - git push ionic master

Everytime it shows timeout error, Old Ionic View used to work like charm , never faced any issue , just $ionic upload and app available for sync. but this new git integration proves to be disappointing , So many places this issue is reported but nowhere it is resolved.

```
      ssh: connect to host git.ionicjs.com port 22: Connection timed out
      fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

      Please make sure you have the correct access rights
      and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Could you solve it in any way?

Comment: @Enrique No , i posted this same issue in ionicforum , they asked me to  try the same same process with a new app (ionic start) and then check the push command  - git push ionic master working or not , may be it's issue with legacy project only. 
But as of now i left this git integration and migrated to legacy with the following command ( ionic config set -g backend.) , and using the old $ionic upload

Comment: Thanks @Chanky i've posted the same too at ionicforums w/o any helpful answer yet